# Loading from pyllamacpp.model gives error "Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)"

Tags: python

I installed [pyllamacpp](https://pypi.org/project/pyllamacpp/) using

`pip install pyllamacpp`

Then, when I tried to run `from pyllamacpp.model import Model` in PyCharm, I get the error:

`Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)`

I am using MacBook Pro with Apple M1 Pro chip.